# variant not pass when use laravel multi language group rout

Tags: laravel, routes, multilingual

i use laravel locale for 3 language as en , fr , ar. i want url to be this method :

*mysite.com/en/posts/23*

*mysite.com/fr/posts/23*

*mysite.com/ar/posts/23*

i use below code for prefix URL by `{locale} = en , fr , ar`
and for sending post id to controller 
but when i use group route and {locale} prefix the id not pass to controller

```
Route::prefix('{locale}')->group(function () {
    Route::get('posts/{id}', 'PostController@singlePage');
});
```

laravel multi language tutorial that i use : [Link Source](https://appdividend.com/2019/04/01/how-to-create-multilingual-website-using-laravel-localization/)

if have other way for that URL format (mysite.com/en/posts/id) guide me 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}'], function () { 
    Route::get('posts/{id}', 'PostController@singlePage');
});
```

Comment: Does your route work directly from browser `en/posts/12` or `fr/posts/12`?